# What is gcloud doing every hour on my local (OSX) developer machine

Tags: macos, security, gcloud

In the directory `~/.config/gcloud/logs` of my Mac I see daily subdirectories and hourly activity logs. Which application/regular job causes these log entries? I sometimes to not use `gcloud` for weeks but have these logs 365*7*24? From the content it looks like it's renewing some credentials.

Comment: gcloud does use temporary credentials for access, so it's likely refreshing those. I'm surprised it's running so much in the background though!

Comment: Can you share a bit of what is being added to those logs? That might make it easier to guess what is being done and determine which service is causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies @nathan-wallace and @rafael-lemos (and a reply on Twitter: https://twitter.com/plaugg/status/1355477864938942465?s=20).

This helped me figure out that the frequent logs come from updates performed by the Google Cloud plugin in IntelliJ (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij). Unfortunately it is closed source so I cannot dig deeper into it. But the updates vanished as soon as I switched off IntelliJ.